# Merge Dataframe in Python with a column and time difference value of 1 minute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am new to python, wanted a help to merge two datafames on :

a) Should have same value in a numeric field `df1_UL_GTP_TEID_0_int` and `df2_TEID_UL_int`

b) difference between df1 `START_TIME_roundoff` and df2 `TS_START_roundoff` should be 1 minute.

```
df1
START_TIME_roundoff UL_GTP_TEID_0_int   TIMSI/MSIN
46  2020-03-10 12:00:00 1196907781  3.240371e+09
190 2020-03-10 12:01:00 1147678181  3.244522e+09
308 2020-03-10 12:05:00 1147678181  3.244522e+09
496 2020-03-10 12:07:00 1691830165  3.252351e+09
632 2020-03-10 12:12:00 1809929829  3.237458e+09

df2
S_START_roundoff    TEID_UL_int DIR
1   2020-10-03 09:59:00 1973380469  1
2   2020-10-03 10:00:00 2041336357  2
4   2020-10-03 12:06:00 1147678181  12
5   2020-10-03 09:57:00 1295205669  1
6   2020-10-03 12:12:00 1809929829  13

<<< Expected OUTPUT >>> 
row 308 of df_1 should merge with row 4 of df_2
and row 632 of df_1 should merge with row 6 of df_2
```

[image: df_1 dataframe]
[image: df_2 dataframe]

logic :

```
If absolute value of |df1.START_TIME_roundoff - df2.TS_START_roundoff| <= 1 then 
df_new = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='inner', left_on='UL_GTP_TEID_0_int', right_on='TEID_UL_int')
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide a copy/pastable data frame that people can work on it.

Comment: added. Is this what you were asking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dataframes below:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': ['2019-01-01 10:00:00', '2019-01-02 12:20:00', '2019-01-01 10:00:00'],
                   'C': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']})
df2= pd.DataFrame({'D': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
                   'E': ['2019-01-01 10:00:59', '2019-01-02 12:21:20', '2019-01-01 09:59:30'],
                   'F': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']})
```

If I understood your condition to join two datasets correctly, below code seems to do the job:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='C', right_on='F', how='inner')
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B']) # Ensure it's datetime
df['E'] = pd.to_datetime(df['E']) # Ensure it's datetime
df['delta']=abs(df['B'] - df['E'])/np.timedelta64(1,'m') # Find the abs diff in minutes
df.query("delta<1").drop(columns='delta')
```

Output is merged dataframe containing ID1 and ID3.

This is probably not the perfect solution as probably could be done in single line of code by someone who is more experienced.

Comment: really appreciate your support. DELTA Query is giving me ERROR : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' . First ) I have converted Both data frames date time into separate columns. Second) Merge Query works well.. But while using the DELTA QUERY it is giving ERROR. I am using this df_join['delta']=abs(df_3dgl_volte['START_TIME_time'] - df_do_volte['TS_START_time'])/np.timedelta64(1,'m')

Comment: Hi Pratyada, just wondering what's the name of the merged dataframe (i.e. equivalent of df in my code). I see you are using two different dataframes: df_3dgl_volte, df_do_volte in calculating delta column. It should be just referencing your merged dataframe instead of two different dataframes.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the names (alias). Query runs well but the final output "DELTA" is not giving any output.. Merge is fine, but dropping the rows with Timedelta more than 1 minute is not giving any output. NAN Values in abs(df_3dgl_volte['START_TIME_time'] - df_do_volte['TS_START_time'])/np.timedelta64(1,'m')

Comment: Is there missing data in your datetime columns? You could check using this code format : df['Column'].isnull().sum(). If you want to filter out missing values, use this df[df['delta'].notnull()]. And then try running the last line again. If these don't help, could you please share the block of coding you are using - it would help me better understand.

Comment: I was doing wrong while selecting the date time column of the data frame.. ITS WORKING NOW !! THANKYOU VERY MUCH Zolzaya. Really appreciate it..

Comment: Your welcome... Sharing a link, if you can help me here... please (very imp) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795083/convert-time-column-in-pandas-from-float-to-actual-time-value